# Calling method from razor page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a asp.net core mvc project.

In my layout file, I want to display the name of the currently logged in user, such that the username is displayed in the header. For this, I want to be able to call a function in my homecontroller that does this.
So, I made a simple function taht looks like this  in the home controller:

```
    public String GetLoggedInuser()
    {
        return "garse garsebro";
    }
```

And then I have tried every method I have been able to find. The first couple of methods here are just function suggested around the web, that are simply not available to me:

```
@HtmlHelper.Action("GetLoggedInuser");
@Html.RenderAction("GetLoggedInuser");
```

To name a few. Then there is this one, which I can find:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("GetLoggedInuser")
```

But for this one, my function "GetLoggedInuser" can't be found anywhere.

How do you, in a razor page call a controller function that you can get returned a string from that function and display it?

Comment: What do you need it for ? you have to show your layout page, your razor page model and  so on.

Comment: I'm a bit uncertain about the question? I need to use it to display a logged in username in the top left header. I don't want to simply pass it the model, because there a several controllers and actions that should render it. Otherwise I would need for all models that return to contain the current loged in users username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity then below line will do the work post login.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not :(

Comment: I'm running linux, and the setup for that has proven to be insane

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ajax to call action to get the username,and add it to html:

```
<div id="username">

</div>
@section scripts
{

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'GetLoggedInuser',
            }).done(function (result) {
                $("#username").html(result);
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```